# combine average function and row number over partition in one query MySQL

Tags: mysql, average, limit, partition-by

This is the database:

| id_user | nama | id_sikap | kelancaran | tahsin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000000 | Budi | B | 90 | 90 |
| 10000000 | Budi | A | 89 | 78 |
| 10000000 | Budi | A | 90 | 90 |
| 10000001 | Ina | A | 84 | 44 |

I want to combine some conditions in one query such as average (tahsin, kelancaran, and akhir), and display the most repeated value in id_sikap

```
    <?php 
        
        $no = 1;
        
        $sql = "SELECT setoran.id_user, user.id_user, user.nama, setoran.id_sikap, 
AVG(kelancaran) AS avg_kelancaran, AVG(tahsin)  AS avg_tahsin, (tahsin + kelancaran)/2 AS akhir, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY setoran.id_user ORDER BY COUNT(setoran.id_sikap) DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM setoran INNER JOIN user ON setoran.id_user=user.id_user GROUP BY setoran.id_user, 
setoran.id_sikap ";
        
        $get = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                                  
        ?>
             <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no ?></td>                      
                <td><?php echo $row['nama']  ?></td>                      
                <td><?php echo $row['id_user'] ?></td>                      
                <td><?php echo $row['cabang'] ?></td>                   
                <td><?php echo $row['avg_kelancaran']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['avg_tahsin'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['id_sikap'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['akhir'] ?></td>
              </tr>                    
        <?php $no++;} 
        ?>
```

but the result end up like this, it can be seen that there is a repetition in id 10000000 and it's not showing the most repeated but show all the data of id_sikap in id 10000000, I've tried using LIMIT and TOP 1 but it's not working

This is the existing result

| id_user | nama | id_sikap | avg_kelancaran | avg_tahsin | akhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000000 | Budi | B | 90 | 90 | 90 |
| 10000000 | Budi | A | 89.5 | 84 | 83.5 |
| 10000001 | Ina | A | 84 | 44 | 50 |

The needed result

| id_user | nama | id_sikap | avg_kelancaran | avg_tahsin | akhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000000 | Budi | A | 89.75 | 87 | 88.375 |
| 10000001 | Ina | A | 84 | 44 | 50 |

Is it possible to combine all the conditions that I need in one query? and how?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you'll need to make another query with `AVG()` function after. So, let's take your current query and inspect where you need to fix:

```
SELECT setoran.id_user, user.id_user, user.nama, setoran.id_sikap, 
       AVG(kelancaran) AS avg_kelancaran, AVG(tahsin)  AS avg_tahsin, 
       /*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         the part above is fine */

       (tahsin + kelancaran)/2 AS akhir, 
       /*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         I'm a bit curious how you calculate this but I think you're looking for the 
        combined value of avg and divide by 2. I'll do this on the second part of the 
        query*/

       ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (PARTITION BY setoran.id_user 
                         ORDER BY COUNT(setoran.id_sikap) DESC LIMIT 1) 
       /*I assume that you already discovered ROW_NUMBER() can't use LIMIT and as 
         far as I know MySQL don't have TOP function. I'll not be using this.*/

FROM setoran 
INNER JOIN user 
ON setoran.id_user=user.id_user 
GROUP BY setoran.id_user, setoran.id_sikap 
/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
I'm pretty sure that you turned off only_full_group_by mode otherwise this query 
won't successfully run with these columns in GROUP BY*/
```

So let's go to the first part of the query:

```
SELECT s.id_user, u.nama, s.id_sikap,
            AVG(s.kelancaran) AS avg_k, AVG(s.tahsin) AS avg_t
      FROM setoran AS s 
    INNER JOIN user AS u
       ON s.id_user=u.id_user
    GROUP BY s.id_user,
             u.nama,
             s.id_sikap
```

I retain most of your original query, added and removed a few parts. I've assigned aliases on the table so it's easier to write (`s.` instead of `setoran.`) and I also added `s.id_sikap` in the `GROUP BY`. We make this base query as a derived table and do another `AVG()` operation on the initial average result:

```
SELECT id_user,
       nama,
       AVG(avg_k) AS avg_kelancaran, 
       AVG(avg_t) AS avg_tahsin,
       (AVG(avg_k)+AVG(avg_t))/2 AS akhir
 FROM
    (SELECT s.id_user, u.nama, s.id_sikap,
            AVG(s.kelancaran) AS avg_k, AVG(s.tahsin) AS avg_t
      FROM setoran AS s 
    INNER JOIN user AS u
       ON s.id_user=u.id_user
    GROUP BY s.id_user,
             u.nama,
             s.id_sikap) AS dt1
GROUP BY id_user,
         nama;
```

I did not include `id_sikap` column here because it made little sense to show the result as `A` for `Budi` since the final average calculation is based on combined `id_sikap` value. However, if you still want to show them, I suggest you add `GROUP_CONCAT(id_sikap)` in `SELECT` instead of just `id_sikap`.

This is the result of the final query:

| id_user | nama | avg_kelancaran | avg_tahsin | akhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000000 | Budi | 89.75 | 87 | 88.375 |
| 10000001 | Ina | 84 | 44 | 64 |

Notice the `akhir` value for `Ina` is different than your expected result of `50` but everything else is the same? I assume that you've made a slight mistake on the calculation since the value `akhir` for `Budi` is correct. If not, then maybe there's a logic behind that. If that's the case, we need to know ya.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8da6e9c62483b9ed80474dff8364d98a)

```
SELECT id_user,
       nama,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           GROUP_CONCAT(id_sikap 
                ORDER BY id_skp_cnt DESC, id_sikap),
                ',',1) AS Most_id_sikap,
       AVG(avg_k) AS avg_kelancaran, 
       AVG(avg_t) AS avg_tahsin,
       (AVG(avg_k)+AVG(avg_t))/2 AS akhir
 FROM
    (SELECT s.id_user, u.nama, s.id_sikap,
            COUNT(s.id_sikap) AS id_skp_cnt,
            AVG(s.kelancaran) AS avg_k, AVG(s.tahsin) AS avg_t
      FROM setoran AS s 
    INNER JOIN user AS u
       ON s.id_user=u.id_user
    GROUP BY s.id_user,
             u.nama,
             s.id_sikap) AS dt1
GROUP BY id_user,
         nama
```

So what I did on the query was adding `COUNT(s.id_sikap) AS id_skp_cnt` in the derived table. The purpose for this is to count how many of the said `id_sikap` appeared in the row based on the grouping condition. Here's the result:

```
+---------+-----+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
|id_user  |nama |id_sikap |id_skp_cnt |avg_k   |avg_t   |
+---------+-----+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
|10000000 |Budi |    B    |    1      |90.0000 |90.0000 |
|10000000 |Budi |    A    |    2      |89.5000 |84.0000 |
|10000001 |Ina  |    A    |    1      |84.0000 |44.0000 |
+---------+-----+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
                              ^^^
                 count results by existing GROUP BY
```

Once I did that, I use a combination of two function; the first one is `GROUP_CONCAT()` where I return `id_sikap` value with `ORDER BY` of the count result in descending order (`DESC`) from the derived table. The result of that will look like this:

| nama | GROUP_CONCAT(id_sikap ORDER BY id_skp_cnt DESC, id_sikap) |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Budi | A, B | The `id_sikap=A` for Budi gets the first position in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` because the count result is larger and I do order by descending |
| Ina | A |  |

As for the second column of `id_sikap` appeared in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` order by, the reason is simple if some of the `id_sikap` have same count then the smaller alphabet value will take the first spot; I leave it for you to decide whether to include or not.

The last function is using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the first position value in the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Omg sorry for the wrong calculation, thank you for the response it helps a lot!!

Comment: so is it not possible for me to show the most frequently appeared value in id_sikap?

Comment: Oh so that's what it is. If so, then there's a way, might be a creative one but it should work. I'll update my answer once I have the solution ya

Comment: There, I just updated it. I would like to explain more but it's a bit hard to type on mobile.

Comment: thank you, i'll be waiting for that

Comment: that's ok, you can type it when you already in your PC or laptop